# Kong - installing/Setting up a Golang microservice - why does it not work?

Tags: go, installation, service, kong

Absolute Kong noob here; I have a small Golang docker container running a simple Api which just returns the datetime (port 3000).
Checked by running http://localhost:3000/timecheck - works.

```
Installed Kong DB version Postgress conform the Kong instructions.

Created a service:

curl -i -s -X POST http://localhost:8001/services \
  --data 'name=ts' \
  --data 'url=http://0.0.0.0:3000'

201 Created

Setup the route:


curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8001/services/ts/routes \
  --data 'paths[]=/ts' \
  --data 'name=ts'

201 created


checked with: curl -X GET http://localhost:8001/services/ts/routes/ts

If I go to http://localhost:8000/ts name resolution failed..

or 

http://localhost:8000/timecheck (timecheck being the handler in Golang)

I am doing something VERY wrong? ANY help would be apperciated!!
```

Comment: Could you update/clarify the questions? Does request to localhost:8000/timecheck works? What do you mean when creating a service pointing to 0.0.0.0? Did you install kong on Docker or VM?

Comment: Well I started afresh - No Luck

Answer (score 0):

request to localhost:8000/timecheck does NOT work

Kong is installed on Docker

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot use 0.0.0.0 as the IP for a target address. It is only used to tell a service to listen on all network interfaces. For the service target url you have to choose a concrete IP address, e.g. 127.0.0.1, or a hostname.

I think the problem besides that is that your service handler is /timecheck, but your route and service sends it to /ts.

If you want requests to `http://localhost:8000/ts` being routed to `http://localhost:3000/timecheck`, then you have to configure your service and route like this (handler path in service target url, strip_path parameter in route):

Created a service:

```
curl -i -s -X POST http://localhost:8001/services \
  --data 'name=ts' \
  --data 'url=http://localhost:3000/timecheck'
```

Setup the route:

```
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8001/services/ts/routes \
  --data 'paths[]=/ts' \
  --data 'name=ts' \
  --data 'strip_path=true'
```